# How to load data from form into request body

Tags: node.js

when i submit the register form ,the data from that register page should be posted on the console.. and I try to print that result using "req.body.Username" , it says undefined and when i view the req in console. The body seems to be an empty set like " {} ", how to post my form details in body to view in console and how to get rid of that "undefined" error?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you've the middleware added in your express code. If not add the below block,

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: bro.. still am facing the same issue, getting same error like"  body: {} " ,body is empty...

Comment: Please update your post with your `express` and `html` code

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `body-parser` if you don't have it, to parse all the requests in your express application.

Steps to do this:

1. Install body-parser

```
npm install body-parser
```

2. Get the body parser in your file which is the entry point of your application

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

3. use the body parser to parse all the requests.

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

You can have a look at the documentation of body-parser for more details :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Hope this would help solve your issue.

Comment: bro. stll facing same issue .. wt to do .. I already written that BodyParser line .. it still says that "body{}"  .. I think the body is still empty